# Using a 6 amp connector instead of the 16 amps provided in Power Supply box ( Corsair RM850)

Tags: power-supply, power, desktop-computer

I purchased a corsair RM850 which comes in the box with a 16 amp power cable to plug into the home socket.

Problem is that I do not have a 16Amp socket in any of my walls.

There are 2 questions which I have,

My system power requirement in PCpartPicker.com shows around 500 Watts since I am for the time being using a lower end GPU due to shortage in supply for a high end GPU.

- Is it ok to use a cheap 15 to 6 amp socket and connect to my 6 amp home socket?
  OR
- Is it ok to swap the provided 16 amp connector with a generic 6 amp wire to connect to my home wall ( since I wont be needing all of the 850 watts right now)?

Below the left one is 6 amp which i got it from a shop , the right one is 16 amp which shipped with the PSU.

EDIT : Voltage in my country is 220v

[image]

Comment: What voltage does your country operate on? That is going to be the key factor here. At 800W with a 120V (nominal) supply your machine could be drawing 6.6A at peak. https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/conversions/common/watts-amps.php This feels more like a general electrical problem than one specific to computer hardware or software.

Comment: 500W at 220v is about 2.3A. If you do manage to get up to 850W, you're still at ~4A at 220v which is within your range. You would need to consider what else is on the same circuit though, as if it's a 6A breaker, you would not be able to put a great deal else on the same circuit.

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks , If you put it in an answer , I can accept it.

Comment: It's really dumb of the manufacturers to supply a 16A plug to countries where everyone uses 6A plugs. At least they should supply an extra 6A plug power cord with instructions about supported load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500W at 220v is about 2.3A. If you do manage to get up to 850W, you're still at ~4A at 220v which is within your range. You would need to consider what else is on the same circuit though, as if it's a 6A breaker, you would not be able to put a great deal else on the same circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Richie, but it would help to either start or end the answer with a sentence that is simple to understand...for people who aren't familiar with electrical jargon. A sentence like "yes, you can use the old 6A power cord".

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer.